# Geocode searchText with State and Country provided shows results outside of State

Tags: here-api

When using the Nokia Here Geocoding Service the State parameter is ignored when searching by searchText: 315 NE 14th Street, State: FL and Country: US.

The only result returned is a location in Louisiana.  Adding the State to the end of the searchText doesn't work either.

Google and MapQuest properly return the result in Florida.  The client does not want to include a city but rather an address, state and country.

I know that the Nokia Here algorithm does not filter down a closely as Google and MapQuest but expected that the inclusion of the State parameter would force the result search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a search area, so you can further narrow down the results. The following **Android** example will return one result in Homestead, Florida City:

```
String query = "315 NE 14th Street Florida US";
GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest(query);
GeoCoordinate areaCenterCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(27.82353, -81.760254);
geocodeRequest.setSearchArea(areaCenterCoordinate , 15000);
```

According to documentation `GeocodeRequest` processes text string queries, so I believe you can omit state or country parameters and add state or country as part of the search term. Please note that multiple results can be returned if they all match to the given search term.

An example on how to use GeoCoder can be found [here](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/geocoder-and-reverse-geocoder-android).

Depending on your use case, maybe consider to use `SearchRequest` instead. If this does not help it would be great if you can provide more details in your question, e.g. what API flavor you are referring to.

Comment: I am using the JavaScript Maps API for JavaScript v3.0.12.5 and this is confirmed behavior without a bounding area: